# How to insert an svg written logotype to a xhtml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, svg

I am trying to put together some xml files and output them in xhtml using an xslt transformation. I go about it by specifiying an xml file called index.xml where I define the other files which I need to use like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="merge.xsl"?>

<dic:dictionary xmlns:dic = "dictionary">
<dic:Logo>Logo</dic:Logo>
<dic:Author>User Name</dic:Author>
<dic:EnglishWords>english</dic:EnglishWords>
<dic:SwedishTranslation>swedish</dic:SwedishTranslation>
<dic:SwedishWords>swedish</dic:SwedishWords><br/>
<dic:EnglishTranslation>english</dic:EnglishTranslation>
</dic:dictionary>
```

Then in my transformation I have a template declaration for the logo like this:

```
<!--Logo-->
 <xsl:template match = "dic:index//Logo">
 <html>
     <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" />
     </head>
     <body>
        <div id = "Logo">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document(concat(.,'.svg'))"/>
        </div>
    </body>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</html></xsl:template>
```

The svg file itself looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>

<?xml-stylesheet href="Style.css" type="text/css"?>

<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="180px" height="70px" viewBox="0 0 180 70" 
     enable-background="new 0 0 180 70" xml:space="preserve" 
     preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">

<line fill="none" stroke="#000000" x1="0" y1="71.533" x2="35.036" y2="5.109"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#000000" x1="91.971" y1="15.767" x2="91.971" y2="71.533"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#000000" x1="146.357" y1="5.109" x2="177.372" y2="71.533"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#000000" x1="0" y1="71.533" x2="177.372" y2="71.533"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#000000" x1="17.518" y1="58.108" x2="82.481" y2="58.108"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#000000" x1="101.459" y1="58.108" x2="161.866" y2="58.108"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#000000" x1="82.481" y1="58.108" x2="91.971" y2="71.533"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#000000" x1="101.459" y1="58.108" x2="91.971" y2="71.533"/>

</svg>
```

However, while this approach works for other xml files it does not for this svg file, as an output I only get the word Logo. I have been looking around everywhere but I don+t see a good example on how to do this. Also when I try to apply a css style sheet in which I have the following

```
#Logo{
width: 300px ;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
}
```

It does not work either...How to make the css work ...?

Any help or info about this will be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The word "Logo" is appearing because of this on the second line from the end of the XSLT (why is this there?): `<xsl:apply-templates/>`. Where are the templates that process the SVG? Hard to give you any advice without those. What is the expected output XML?

Comment: There is no template that processes the svg.. I just need to output the svg logo on the top of the resulting document. I

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest trying Martin's suggestion and trying `<xsl:copy-of>`, or perhaps `<xsl:copy-of select="document(concat(., '.svg'))/*"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<!--Logo-->
<xsl:template match = "dic:dictionary/dic:Logo">
 <html>
     <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" />
     </head>
     <body>
        <div id = "Logo">
            <xsl:copy-of select="document(concat(.,'.svg'))/*"/>
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>
```

You need to remove the `<xsl:apply-templates>` at the end (that's what's reproducing the "Logo" text), and use `<xsl:copy-of>` to copy the contents of the SVG file.

Comment: I have just done as above but the word logo keeps showing up instead of the actual logo..... Is there something that I have to do to the svg file?

Comment: Your XSLT doesn't seem to be consistent with the input XML.  I would expect the `match=` value should be `/dic:dictionary/dic:Logo` rather than what you have there.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: yes that did it... thank you so much...!!! However I used 

match = "dic:dictionary/dic:Logo"> without the initial forward slash... I also have a warning:

file:///usr/share/xml/svg/svg11.dtd:2278: validity warning : Attribute space of element style: already defined
    type %ContentType.datatype; #REQUIRED

What can that be?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think it's because of the `<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">` in the .svg file.  Would it be possible to remove that, or does it have to be there in the .svg file?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply `<xsl:copy-of select="document(concat(., '.svg'))"/>` instead of the `apply-templates`? Or do you want to transform the SVG in some way? And it is not clear where the path or file name to the SVG document is contained in the XML input sample.

Comment: no the .svg does not need to be transformed  just needs to be outputted in the resulting document.... The path or filename is 

<dic:Logo>Logo</dic:Logo> 

which is specidied on the index.xml file; the first code sample....